# Is android.hardware.telephony required for app that sends sms and uses internet, it doesn't make phone calls?

Tags: android, sms, tablet, telephony

Ok, i have a simple question. I have app on market that calls numbers and sends sms, and can browse internet. That app is supported to 469 devices (on market). Although I can install my app on tablets, i want to give posibility to tablet users, so they can browse it on market. So i am using multiple apk solution on the market. Now both of my app are using android.hardware.telephony as feature, so it cant be supported by tablets (on market). I wonder in second app, if I remove this feature, will i still be able to send sms, i don't need phone calls ??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you use a certain feature on the device it does not need to be required. In your manifest you can specify android:required=["true" | "false"] in your uses-feature tag. Just make sure you handle the scenario when the user doesn't have that feature.

Comment: Ok, but please can you be specific with my case. I will ask simpler question - if I write this in my manifest file:

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS"></uses-permission>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.telephony" android:required="false" />

Is this going to work ?? That is all. yes or no :)

Comment: <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.telephony" android:required="false" /> will make your app available to users on the market without that feature on their device.

Comment: And with this line in my manifest, my app will still be able to send SMS ??

Comment: Yes. As long as you keep the SEND_SMS permission.

Comment: I know I'm a bit late to the party but from the comments one might be confused to think that a device which **does not** have `android.hardware.telephony` will still be able to send SMS messages, this is false. You can't send SMS messages without having `android.hardware.telephony`. Just saying.

Comment: The question has been - do I need telephony feature declared even when I am sending SMS, which may or may not related with the telephony. So in case of my mobile app, do I have to declare telephony feature  - I am not looking for required is "false" as an answer; of course that will do the job. But the real question is telephone referenced to the sms at all? - the answer is here https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-feature-element.html#permissions  Yes for sending SMS you need uses-feature for telephony. However to support tablet you can set to required is "false"